# How can I use JavaScript logic to declare QML properties?

Tags: qt, qml

This is my attempt to use JavaScript logic to declare a QML property with a certain value. When I debug this block, the code never goes further than the first line:

```
property point timeWindow: {
    var tW = Qt.point(0, internalSettings.defaultTimeWindowSize)

    if (fitWidth) {
        return fitToWidth(tW);
    }

    return tW
}
```

I can also guess from the documentation that this is not supported unless I wrap the JavaScript in a function and a `Qt.binding(function() {...})`. But in this case I don't need a binding, just an initial value.

What is the right way to go about this?

Comment: Where is `fitWidth` defined?

Comment: @sk2212: I think you are right. When I changed that reference to another variable, the code executed. I seem to have misinterpreted an error in my code as QML working differently than I thought. But QML was not to blame.